# QGIS 3.10 .qgz~ backup file

Tags: qgis, file-formats, save, data-backup

I noticed that xxx.qgz~ (BackupVersion) is no longer saved with this version. My research found that a backup file is still being created. All of my projects with this version did not create any.

Is there a setting that I have wrong or what is the reason that the file no longer appears?